# Building OPENCV For CARMA

Tags: opencv

I got the following error when I run `make`

```
[ 27%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_highgui
**Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so**
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtk-x11-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk-x11-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -latk-1.0
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lpangoft2-1.0
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lpangocairo-1.0
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.5.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can disable GTK support in CMake: -DWITH_GTK=OFF -DWITH_GSTREAMER=OFF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your target system is missing GTK libs. 
I don't know all missing libraries you reported, but you definitely need libgtk-2-dev along with it's dependencies.

You will also need Cairo and Pango libraries, but I don't know if they are included in GTK or not.

To get these libraries open you package manager and look for GTK 2.0, or do
`apt-get -f install libgtk-2-dev` from terminal. If you have `aptitude` of course.

Other option would be to install QT libraries and update OpenCV makfiles to link against QT.

EDIT:
I'm not Linux guru, so for directions how to install arbitrary libraries, you should refer to appropriate section of StackExchange (SuperUser, Linux, Ubuntu, ...).

Or in case you have some different platform to forums dedicated to that platform.